# How can I access specific parts of a string in a txt file with python?

Tags: python

So I have a large text file with a lot of lines of HTML that was nicely created by a webcrawler. It's full of lines that look like the code below. I'm wondering, How can I just get a new text file full of just the "desired text" instead of the entire line of html code?

```
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 1</a></b>'
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 2</a></b>'
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 3</a></b>'
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 4</a></b>'
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 5</a></b>'
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 6</a></b>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at BeautifulSoup, the examples have a demo on exactly that problem:

[Beautiful Soup Quick Intro](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

[EDIT]
Detailed solution for your case attached:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 1</a></b>'
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 2</a></b>'
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 3</a></b>'
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 4</a></b>'
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 5</a></b>'
b'<b><a href="example.html" target="_blank">Desired Text 6</a></b>'
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
print soup.getText()
```

Comment: @Chris: This isn't a link-only answer as it gives the solution "use BeautifulSoup", though that is still very thin for an answer.

Comment: Chris, I am unsure how to handle this: If I write a comment, the question remains open, and there is no point copying the code. Should I flag the question as duplicate?

Comment: @tfv: A duplicate of what? Yes, construct an example and explain why using this library is the best solution. You're correct that providing this information in a comment would be inappropriate.

Comment: @Scriptomaniac: HTML parsing cannot safely be done trivially like that, no. You will have to put in more than five seconds' effort, sorry. (Well, okay, if you are certain that the format is fixed, you can simple use the string manipulation functions, no? Did you read the documentation yet?)

Comment: Nice one tfv. Can't upvote as I'm out of votes today lol sorry

Comment: Ha, even though it's directed at me - nice one. I have looked at the documentation and tried it, I just keep getting Type errors. Ideally my web crawler would just write only the text that I need into the new file, but I kept having problems with that too.